# How to deduce the uniform ellipticity condition from an integral condition

Tags: analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open set, and let $A$ be a $N\times N$ symmetric matrix with entries in $L^\infty(\Omega, \mathbb{R})$, such that for some positive $\lambda$ and $\Lambda$ the following inequalities hold for every $u \in W^{1,2}_0(\Omega, \mathbb{R})$:
$$ 
\lambda \int \limits_\Omega \! | \nabla u(x) |^2 \, \mathrm{d}x \leq \int \limits_\Omega \! A(x) \nabla u(x) \cdot \nabla u(x) \, \mathrm{d} x \leq \Lambda \int \limits_\Omega \! | \nabla u(x) |^2 \, \mathrm{d}x
$$
Is there a way to deduce that $A$ satisfies the following pointwise inequalities
$$
\lambda | \xi |^2 \leq A(x) \xi \cdot \xi \leq \Lambda |\xi|^2
$$
for almost every $x \in \Omega$ and for all $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^N$?

The *first strategy* I tried to adopt was to choose a function in $W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)$ whose gradient is essentially a fixed vector $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^N$. However, to choose it in such a way that it belongs to $W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)$ it must vanish near the boundary. Hence I chose
$$
u(x) := (\xi \cdot x ) \zeta(x)
$$
where $\zeta$ is a cutoff function such that $\zeta \equiv 1$ on $\omega \subset \subset \Omega$ and with support in $\Omega$. Maybe, if it is convenient, we can also control $|\nabla \zeta|$ when $\partial{\omega}$ is "near" $\partial{\Omega}$. But I don't see how to obtain the pointwise estimates from the intagral ones!

*Second strategy*. I tried to argue by contradiction. Assume, for example, that the inequality
$$
\lambda |\xi|^2 \leq A(x) \xi \cdot \xi
$$
doesn't hold for almost every $x \in \Omega$ for some $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^N$. This means that the set
$$
\omega := \{ x \in \Omega \ | \ \lambda |\xi|^2 > A(x) \xi \cdot \xi \}
$$
has positive measure. If I was able to construct a function in $W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)$ whose gradient is $\xi$ on $\omega$ and $0$ in $\Omega \setminus \omega$, I would conclude integrating, contradictiong the first intregral inequality. Though such function cannot be constructed in that precise way, maybe I can argue as in the *first strategy* using suitable cutoff functions, but my tries failed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

A sketch of what you should do.

1. Show that if $g(x)$ is a $L^\infty$ function such that $\int |g(x) \phi(x)|\mathrm{d}x \leq \Lambda \int |\phi(x)|\mathrm{d}x$ for every $\phi\in C^\infty_0$ then $|g(x)| \leq \Lambda$. (Hint, suppose not, let $S = \{ |g(x)| > \Lambda\}$ has positive measure. Let $\phi_{\eta,\epsilon}(x)$ be a mollified (with parameter $\eta$) version of the indicator function $\mathbf{1}_{S\cap \Omega_\epsilon}$ where $\Omega_\epsilon$ is the subset of $\Omega$ that is at least $\epsilon$ distance from the boundary. Take $\eta,\epsilon$ sufficiently small. For small $\epsilon$ we guarantee that $S\cap \Omega_\epsilon$ has positive measure. For small $\eta$ we guarantee that $\mathrm{supp}(\phi_{\eta,\epsilon})$ has arbitrarily small measure.)
2. Similarly work with the lower bound $\lambda$.
3. Choose your test function $u$ in your original problem to be something of the form 
   $$ u_{\eta,\epsilon,k}(x) = \phi_{\eta,\epsilon}(x) \exp(i k x\cdot\xi) \in C^\infty_0(\Omega) \tag{*}$$
   and take $k \to \infty$ (sufficiently large depending on the choice of $\eta$ and $\epsilon$ so that the term corresponding to $k^2 A\xi\cdot\xi$ "swamps" the contribution when the derivative falls on $\phi_{\eta,\epsilon}$).

Note that this is more akin to your second strategy.

---

A short word on the form (*): one should think of the scaling in $\eta$ as sharpening the support of the function $u$. But by the uncertainty principle this will necessarily broaden the Fourier support. We compensate this by doing a translation on the Fourier side (corresponding to increasing $k$, a phase shift in physical space). The end result is that while the size of the Fourier support is huge, we can make it concentrated in an arbitrarily small **angular** neighborhood of the ray corresponding to $\xi$. (Remember, a small angle can still give lots of room if you go far enough away from the origin.)

That we can use this method of proof hinges on the fact that $A\xi\cdot \xi$ is homogeneous in scale for $\xi$, and the only part that is important is the direction!